# Creating a range of numbers out of a single number

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to take a list of quantities for multiple orders. I have a macro that separates the orders in my table with a blank line. I need to convert the numbers into a range. Example order one takes 8 peaces for one item then 6 pieces for another. The first range would be 1-8 and the second range would be 9-14. Once the macro hits a blank line, I need it to reset so that the next order starts at 1 and moves on.

Here is an example of what I'm looking for it to do:

[image]

I dint try much. I used regular formulas, but I can't do that on everyone.

Comment: Why the input 6 qty is followed by 22 instead of 17 following your logic? Also, why the second input 15 is 1-16? Shouldn't it be 1-15?

Answer (score 1):

I think your second example is wrong because it does not follows your logic:

[image]

So based on rest of inputs, you can do like this:

[image]

Formula in cell B3:

```
=IF(A3="";"";IF(A2="";1;C2+1))
```

Formula in cell C3:

```
=IF(A3="";"";B3+A3-1)
```

Just drag down